Can't display html content with WebView from external file
Hi I'm trying to display html content from external file located on my hard drive with WebView. There is also reference to js file inside the html. When I run my program the output window is empty. I'am using Intellij IDEA. My source files look like this:
js file src.js:
function foo()
{
document.getElementById("t1").innerText="test"
}

html file h.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="C:\bo\src.js"></script>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<button onClick="foo()">
    <div id="t1">click me</div>
</button>
</body>
</html>

This is my Java source code:
@FXML
private WebView webView;

public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        webView.getEngine().load("C:/bo/h.html");
        loadPage();
    }

I expect when I run my application to see the web page in the output window. I also expect when I click on button the text to change from "click me" to "test". What I'am doing wrong ? The main idea is to diaplay html content linked to external js file. When I put the html content as an argument I can see the web page in the output window but the button won't change the text because the js file is not accessible. Does the WebView provide the best way to display HTML content in javafx application that run on Windows PC. If it's not, suggest a better way to display web content please.

The argument to load is a (string representation of a) URL, not a file path. It doesn’t really make any sense to load the HTML from a hard-coded file location, but if you were going to do that you would use something like new File(…).toURI().toString()

Thank you @James_D ! Now I can access the html file from java code, but  html can't access the js. When I click on the button text won't change.

In the HTML don't use an absolute path reference.  Instead use a relative reference, and place the JavaScript file in a location relative to the HTML.  For example <script type="text/javascript" src="src.js"></script> if the file src.js is in the same folder as your html file or <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/src.js"></script> if src.js is in a folder scripts located in the same location as your HTML. (I didn't try it, but it should work...)

For an absolute reference, you would need to also use an absolute URL in your HTML, which generally you don't want to do, unless you are sourcing the JavaScript from a remote location (e.g. a https: URL that references a google JavaScript library provided by a content distribution network - CDN), though file:///C:/bo/src.js may work.  Some browser implementations block file urls for security reasons, so it might not work.

See if this can help.

I changed my code as per suggestions, my code still won't work as I expect.                                                                                                                                                                                                        When I run the html through chrome or firefox it runs as I expect. The problem is that HTML can't reach js file.
